# unused @Repository class will cause memory leak

Tags: java, memory-leaks, heap-memory, heap-dump

unused @Repository class will cause memory consumption

Our production application server go down very frequently and we tried analyzing the heap dump using eclipse memory analyzer tool.

Found that some `char []` objects are taking more memory.

so for this issue we analyzed our application code and found that one `@Repository` class which was unused.

Will this unused `@Repository` class may cause this memory issue ?

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;


@Repository
public class BenchCommentDAOImpl extends BaseDAOImpl<BenchComment> implements BenchCommentDAO {

    
}
```

***update 1***

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "bnch_cmnt")
public class BenchComment extends BaseCrudEntity<Integer> implements Serializable {
     private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

     @Id
     @Column(name = "cmnt_id")
     @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
     private Integer id;
     
     @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
     @JoinColumn(name = "bnch_id", referencedColumnName = "bnch_id")
     @JsonBackReference
     private Bench bench;

     @Column(name = "bnch_id" , insertable=false ,updatable=false)
     private Integer benchId;

     @Column(name = "xtrnl_cmnt")
     private String comment;

}
```

`@Repository` class is extended from `BenchComment` class which is having `comment` as string field.

Hence in the heap dump analyzer am seeing some values with are matching with this `comment` field. That is where my doubt happening.

***Update 2***

```
@JsonManagedReference
@OneToMany(mappedBy="bench",cascade=CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.EAGER,orphanRemoval=true)
     private List<BenchComment> benchComments;
```

We do have `OneToMany` relationship with `FetchType.EAGER` for `BenchComment` pojo class. Will this implementation cause this heap leaks issue.?

Comment: I don't see how this Repository could be connected to `char[]` objects that are taking a lot of memory according to you.

Comment: @Amongalen I have updated my question with `BenchComment` pojo class where it is extended by `@Repository` class.

Comment: Found the solution. Look at the edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that your memory-leaks have anything to do with this empty repository.
In other projects, I saw unused repositories, but I never heard of any memory leaks.

Maybe there some other possible things:

1. **Eager-Relations**
   Two objects, which are connected (e.g. with `@JoinColumn`) can cause an `OutOfMemoryException` if they fetch themselves in `EAGER`-mode.
   (They will fetch each other recursively until your RAM is empty)
2. [java.lang.OutOfMemoryException: java heap space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7863845/java-lang-outofmemoryexception-java-heap-space)
3. [Detecting out of memory errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11508310/detecting-out-of-memory-errors)

The empty repository doesn't mean, that your object never gets fetched from the database. If you have relations between your objects, then they may appear sometimes in your HEAP.

If you can find the cause, then we will be happy, when you posting it here.

### Edit

To your edit with `FetchType.EAGER`: Yes it is your problem!
In `Bench` you are fetching the `BenchComments` eagerly and in `BenchComments` you are fechting the `Bench` eagerly. A vicious circle.

Just remove the `EAGER`-fetch-types and you should be fine.

Comment: I have updated my question. We having `OneToMany` relationship. will that cause this issue.?

Comment: The default-fetch-type of `OneToMany` is `LAZY` - this should be fine. Maybe you are using some others (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26601032/default-fetch-type-for-one-to-one-many-to-one-and-one-to-many-in-hibernate/42168093)

Comment: Did you wrote a `.toString()`-method (or something familiar) which are using these lazy-fields? (I saw this before, but it results in a `StackOverflowError`)

Comment: instead of using `fetch=FetchType.EAGER` do i need to change it as `fetch=FetchType.LAZY`  ?

Comment: Yes, or just remove it. The default-types should be fine.

Comment: Thanks.. let me try and update the outcome on this.

Comment: Still our implementation is not done.. i will definitly keep posted on the same once i complete my implementation and testing. I feel then its meaningful